# Dot before numbering

Tags: numbering

I have a problem with numbering. Everywhere is a dot before the number. Like equation numbering, figures numbering etc. Does anyone know how to remove it?

[image]

[image]

Thank you a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Please post not only a couple of screenshots but the actual code -- preferably in the form of a Minimum Working Example that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` -- that generates the problem.

Comment: That is not the default behaviour so the answer is don't do whatever you did that made latex do that, but as you have not given any clues, it is hard to say more. I would guess that you have a document class with chapters and have gone `\renewcommand\thechapter{}` to hide the number but the `.` separating the chapter number is still there but that is only a wild guess.

Comment: Thank you for advice Mico, you're right. I am new in TeX and I don`t had any idea where the mistake should be.

David, you guessed it well. Before \begin{document} I had \renewcommand\thechapter{}. Now it works!(e.g. Table 2.3:)

Thank you a lot!

Comment: If you use a an "at sign" in comments like @Mico then the person will get notified, otherwise they may not pass by again and see your reply:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In document classes that have chapters, for example the standard report and book classes, it is normal for numbering to be "within the chapter" so that the second equation in chapter 4 is (4.2).  If you hide the chapter number with

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
```

then the number will go but the separator will still be there so you would get (.2).

The solution is not to do that but instead do something else. If you do not want chapters the simplest thing is to use article class instead, but it is of course possible to customise report to have chapters but not to number equations within the chapter.

Comment: When omitting the chapter from section numbers, one presumably also does not want to restart numbering at each chapter.  `\usepackage{chngctr}` and its `\counterwithout` command can take care of both at once.