# Dot before Chapter and Section numbers

Tags: numbering, counters

My Chapter numbers come out to me `Chapter .1` instead of `Chapter 1`. This problem persists throughout in section as well as ToC.

A similar question is answered earlier, [Dot before numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175148/dot-before-numbering), but it does not work in my case.

(Posting a MWE will take a lot of time, which I am running against.)
 Any suggestion?

Comment: Posting solutions to something with errors takes a lot of time... Any suggestion? This has nothing to do with `latex3`. I assume, that some the counter formatting is just wrong

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to remove the dot before the number or to add it after it? Posting a MWE takes as little time as a minute. You only need to post the preamble, an example title section and some wording. Maybe two title sections, throw in some Lipsum wording and you're done.

Comment: On second thought, even just your preamble may be enough. Edit your question and paste the code between `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}`.

Comment: Are you using a `\part` at all? What does `\show\thechapter` reveal in your `.log`?

Answer (score 2):

The following reproduces the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\thechapter` is defined to include `\thepart.`. Also, the `part` counter is typically set using `\Roman` (as in `\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}`). As such, if you don't have any `\part`s in your document,  `\@Roman{0}` (the expansion on zero-counter part) defaults to nothing leaving you with the leading `.` in the `chapter` (and sub-hierarchical counter representations).

Either find and remove the `part`-included version of `\thechapter`, or redefine it in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
```

Some debugging might very the above assumption: Include `\show\thechapter` somewhere in your document, and investigate the `.log` at that point. It may show

```
> \thechapter=\long macro:
->\thepart .\arabic {chapter}.
```

or something similar.